# enviar correo outlook con adjunto con c#

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms, .net

quiero poder enviar una imagen adjunta
pero no encuentro la forma de que se mande por correo como adjunta
y asi pueda editar mas texto dentro del correo

este es mi codigo

```
   using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Net.Configuration;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Net.Security;
    namespace AmazonSESSample
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
                correo.From = new MailAddress("rober.josue.mendoza@hotmail.com", "Kyocode", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);//Correo de salida
                correo.To.Add("robertomendoza@cmg.mx"); //Correo destino?
                correo.Subject = "Correo de prueba"; //Asunto
                correo.Body = "Este es un correo de prueba desde c#"; //Mensaje del correo
                correo.filename = "C:\ruta\img.png"; 
                correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
                correo.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com"; //Host del servidor de correo
                smtp.Port = 25; //Puerto de salida
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("rober.josue.mendoza@hotmail.com", "Cambiomipassword");//Cuenta de correo
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;//True si el servidor de correo permite ssl
                smtp.Send(correo);
    
            }
        }
        }
```

entoces solo quiero que se mande una imagen que esta en mi ruta c:\ruta\img
para que a su vez lo confirme por correo
y este le llege con cc
ya que agregare varios
usuarios de correo por dominio
el siguiente error me lo marca en la linea de la ruta de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso debería tener un método parecido a esto:  correo.Attachments.Add() y me parece que si es una imagen debe agregarla como arreglo de bites

Comment: Revisaste en la documentación si ese atributo filename significa lo que crees que significa?

Comment: ya los cheque pero no supe implementar el filename en la variable correo.filename

Answer (score 1):

ya me salio solo debia agregar las propiedades de
adjuntos para que los leyera y tambien correo.attachments.add(data)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
namespace AmazonSESSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string filename = @"C:\ruta\img.png";
            Attachment data = new Attachment(filename);

            MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
            correo.From = new MailAddress("rober.josue.mendoza@hotmail.com", "Kyocode", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);//Correo de salida
            correo.To.Add("robertomendoza@cmg.mx"); //Correo destino?
            correo.Subject = "Correo de prueba"; //Asunto
            correo.Body = "Este es un correo de prueba desde c#"; //Mensaje del correo
            correo.Attachments.Add(data);

            correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
            correo.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com"; //Host del servidor de correo
            smtp.Port = 25; //Puerto de salida
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("rober.josue.mendoza@hotmail.com", "micontraseña");//Cuenta de correo
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;//True si el servidor de correo permite ssl
            smtp.Send(correo);

        }
    }
    }
```